# Prove this Cauchy integral $\oint_C \frac{f'(z)}{z-z_0}dz = \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

How can I prove that?

I know if I do $\frac{d}{dz}(f(z)/(z-z_0)) = \frac{f'(z)}{z-z_0} - \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}$, but if I put this derivative as zero, I will have these two terms on the right being equal.

Can I then just put that term in the Cauchy integral and say that they are the same?

The question: [http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cautis/calcIV02/cpx3.pdf](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecautis/calcIV02/cpx3.pdf) -> page 12, ex 9b

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the fact that C is a closed curve (which is marked by the symbol $\oint$.

For an open curve from $z_1$ to $z_2$ we'd have
$$ \int_C \frac{d}{dz} \big(\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\big) dz = \frac{f(z_2)}{z_2-z_0} -\frac{f(z_1)}{z_1-z_0}$$
but for a closed curve we have $z_1=z_2$, so
$$ \oint_C \frac{d}{dz} \big(\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\big) dz = 0$$
Calculating the derivative you get the equality you want.

Another way: If $f(z)$ is holomorphic in the whole region bounded by $C$ (which we didn't have to assume in the previous method) we can use the Cauchy formula
$$ \oint_C \frac{g(z)}{z-z_0}dz = g(z_0)$$
with $g(z)=f'(z)$; then we get
$$ \oint_C \frac{f'(z)}{z-z_0}dz = f'(z_0)$$
On the other hand
$$ f'(z_0) = \frac{d}{dz_0} f(z_0) = \frac{d}{dz_0} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz =  \oint_C \frac{\partial}{\partial z_0}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} dz=  \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2} dz$$

Comment: ooooh It makes sense. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Is there any other way to prove it if I use:
$f'(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}dz$?

Comment: @Klein Yes, but only if you assume that $f$ is holomorphic in the region bounded by $C$.