# Proving $\oint_C \frac{f'(z)}{z-z_0}dz = \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I have to prove that.
$$\oint_C \frac{f'(z)}{z-z_0}dz = \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}dz$$

I found a similar question here: [Prove this Cauchy integral $\oint_C \frac{f'(z)}{z-z_0}dz = \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}dz$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4072635/prove-this-cauchy-integral-oint-c-fracfzz-z-0dz-oint-c-fracfz)

However, I still have some confusions.

If I do $$f'(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}dz$$

on the other hand,
$$f'(z_0) = \frac{d}{dz_0}f(z_0)$$
I'm not sure how to get $f(z_0)$. I thought $$f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}$$
but, it don't seems to work like that.

I'm trying to find $f(z_0)$ using cauchy's formula. I'm not sure if this is the right way to find $f(z_0)$.

$$\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^n} = \frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!} \frac{d^{n-1}f(z)}{dz^{n-1}}$$

thus,
$$f(z_0) =  \frac{f'(z)}{1}$$ which is obviously not right.

Comment: This has  a clear answer in yuor link. What is it that you don't understand in that answer? The integral of  a derivative over a closed contour is always $0$.

Comment: Beware: $ \frac{d}{dz_0}$ in formula $f'(z_0) = \frac{d}{dz_0}f(z_0)$ is meaningless: you cannot differentiate with respect to a constant.

Comment: @JeanMarie In my link Adam use $f'(z_0) = \frac{d}{dz_0} f(z_0) = \frac{d}{dz_0} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz$. I don't know how to find $f(z_0) = \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz$.
Futhermore, I have to use $f'(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^2}dz$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I know the integral of a derivative over a closes contour is 0. I was talking about the second way to prove it.

Comment: Of course there are hyptheses (that you have not stated) required for this proof.

Comment: @GEdgar And how he get that? That's my question. Am I on the right path? Wasn't my question clear?

Comment: You did not say $f$ is analytic, or where, you did not say $C$ is a closed curve, you did not say that $C$ is somehow related to $z_0$, etc.

Comment: @GEdgar f is analytic and $z_0$ is inside the curve$. I though it was impossible to prove that if f wasn't analytic that's why I didn't mention that.